# Unable to Edit a Cell (AGGrid Cell Editing) on (Primefaces) Dialog (when modal=true)

Tags: primefaces, ag-grid

Cell editing only works when the modal attribute is false. 
The cell input text doesn't show what the user types.
Specification:

- Primefaces Version: 13.0.0
- AG-Grid Version: 30.1.0

Sample Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      lang="en">

<h:head>
   ......
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community@30.1.0/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js">
</head>

<h:body
  <p:dialog id="maindialog" widgetVar="maindialog" header="Main"  width="800px" modal="true">
     <div id="aggridid"style="width:100%; height: 600px" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
  </p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>

<script>
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'athlete' },
    { field: 'age' },
    { field: 'country' },
    { field: 'year' },
    { field: 'date' },
    { field: 'sport' },
    { field: 'gold' },
    { field: 'silver' },
    { field: 'bronze' },
    { field: 'total' },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    editable: true,
    cellDataType: false,
  },
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#aggridid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

  // do http request to get our sample data - not using any framework to keep the example self contained.
  // you will probably use a framework like JQuery, Angular or something else to do your HTTP calls.
  fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => gridOptions.api.setRowData(data));
});
</script>
```

It works after I try to remove the "ag-cell-inline-editing" and "ag-row-inline-editing" classes in debugging console mode(F12). 
Any idea what the issue could be ?